# Error with bootstrap 3: modal and $_GET my ID

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap, get, modal-dialog

Hello I am using bootstrap to update users profile for my web site but lately I decided to modify some forms of it and I have some problem to send the user ID into $_GET to retrieve all the profile infos and fill all the modal textbox with the data.

I don't know where I've been wrong but I've tried to pass it with my script but it has not worked yet.

I have that error: **Notice: Undefined index: mId in**

This my code:

This is my modal:

```
<div id="exampleModal3" class="modal fade"  aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel3">Editar requisición de compras </h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

<form method="POST">
<?php
$id =  $_GET['mId'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
{
?>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="recipient-name1" class="control-label">ID:</label>
<input type="text" class="id form-control"  name="mId" id="mId" >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="recipient-name2" class="control-label">Username:</label>
<input type="text" class="username form-control" name="username" id="recipient-name2"  value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="recipient-name3" class="control-label">Firstname:</label>
<input type="text" class="firstname form-control" name="firstname" id="recipient-name3"  value="<?php echo $row['firstname']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="recipient-name4" class="control-label">Lastname:</label>
<input type="text" class="lastname form-control" name="lastname" id="recipient-name4" value="<?php echo $row['lastname']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="recipient-name5" class="control-label">Email:</label>
<input type="text" class="email form-control" name="email" id="recipient-name5" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="recipient-name6" class="control-label">Password:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="password" id="recipient-name6" >
</div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
<button type="submit" name="Modify" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This my table where I list all my users, and my button to call my modal.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>LastName</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<td>

<button type="button" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-xs btn-warning" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" data-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModal3" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>

</td>
<td ><?php echo $row['username'];?></td>
<td ><?php echo $row['firstname'];?></td>
<td ><?php echo $row['lastname'];?></td>
<td ><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And this is my script:

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
var myId = $(this).data('id');
$(".modal-body #mId").val(myId);
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "nothing works".

Comment: Hello , I mean I can't pass my ID into $_GET to search the data of my user.

Comment: It's better to edit your answer to improve it. Read also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you, I have modified my question I hope this'll help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on the website http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/7922 :

in the modal.php

```
 <div class="modal-header">

 <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>

 <h3>Modal header</h3>

 </div>

 <div class="modal-body">

 <?php

 $post_id = $_GET['ID'];

  echo $post_id;

 ?>

 </div>

 <div class="modal-footer">

 <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>

 </div>
```

in my index php:

my button to call my modal:

```
 <a href="modal.php?ID= WHAT ID YOU WANT " data-toggle="modal"Modal</a>
```

my script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">


  $('[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var href = $(this).attr('href');

  if (href.indexOf('#') == 0) {

  $(href).modal('open');

  } else {

 $.get(href, function(data) {

 $('<div class="modal">' + data + '</div>').modal();

 });

}

});

</script>
```

hope it will help someone !!!!